# Error correction with 8b/10b encoding

Tags: error-correction

I am contemplating forward error correction on a vhf/audio modem link.  I am using 8b/10b encoding.  Its a little unclear to me where to begin if I want to use error correction.

To apply FEC with the 8b/10b encoding, would this typically start at the pre or post encoded level?

I have been searching for micro-controller targeted error correction libraries or code, haven't been able to come with much.

Comment: This is a very broad question, and is also a bit confusing. 8b/10b is normally only used on a binary channel, and audio modems are usually not binary channels. But in general, channel coding methods and FEC methods are handled separately, although they are often chosen to complement each other. FEC can be divided into two broad categoreis: bit level, such as convolutional coding and Viterbi decoding, and the symbol (byte) level, such as BCH and Reed-Solomon encodings. Each category has different strengths against various types of interference. Can you make your question a little more specific?

Comment: Although this isn't a binary channel, the same principles apply, as a single bit flipped will have unpredictable effects on the decoded output.

Comment: Robert Lacoste's article in circuit cellar got me thinking down this path.  So far its working at 4k baud on a 3k band audio channel.  OFDM doesn't work because of distortion and lack of dynamic range.

Answer (score 3):

8b/10b coding is mainly a spectrum shaping code, not an error correcting code. It ensures a minimum transiton density and no dc content, which are useful properties in ac-coupled transmission paths.

8b/10b codes do allow *detecting* single-bit errors, but not correcting them.